# Combining Convex and Concave in CVX

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Hello,

I have an unconstrained optimization in which I need to minimize a sum of convex functions and maximize a concave function together. I combined both the problem by adding a minus sign to the concave function. The CVX toolbox is giving the following error:

*message: 'Disciplined convex programming error:
Illegal operation: {convex} + {concave}'*

What is the traditional way to do this?

Thank you.

--
Santhosh

Comment: as this is a question about particular software, it would probably be best to contact the authors directly, unless this is covered in some manual already.

Comment: It appears that you think you've got {convex} - {concave}, but CVX thinks you've got {convex} + {concave}.  I'd carefully check what you're doing and if it still seems write to you, then contact the authors of CVX.  